# How to edit the apple developer account

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

Is it possible to edit the date of birth provided while creating the Apple Id

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to your apple account here :

https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage/security

Answer your security questions. Birth Date is the last option.